# About fwrite in php

Tags: php, pdo

I am creating file in php by using `fwrite`. I need to attach the database to my `index.php` My doubt is can I print the below line on `fwrite`? I have tried it but it shows error. Is there any way for this?

```
$fd =fopen("database.php","w");

fwrite($fd, "$dbhost='localhost';
    $dbuser='$user';
    $dbpass='$pass';
    $dbname='$email';
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$email', $dbuser, $dbpass);");

fclose($fd);
```

Comment: *i have tried it but it shows error* - what error did it show?

Comment: @AravindVenkat, do you wanto any actual variable values in the string or all of them should be literals?

Comment: Its like am creating account for the new user, so i need to keep his user name or email as his database name

Comment: Why don't you keep that data in the database? Create one database for your stuff and use data from there to access the user database stuff...

Comment: Based on your previous comment, it looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing errors because the variables aren't escaped. To fix this issue, either swap out the quote markes with single quote marks or add a backslash () infront of $.

```
$fd=fopen("database.php","w");

fwrite($fd,"\$dbhost='localhost';
\$dbuser='\$user';
\$dbpass='\$pass';
\$dbname='\$email';

\$dbh=newPDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=\$email',\$dbuser,\$dbpass);");

fclose($fd);
```

Or the quote mark fix:

```
fwrite($fd, '$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="$user";
$dbpass="$pass";
$dbname="$email";

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$email", $dbuser, $dbpass);');
```

Both should work.

If you want to pass variables to the text (like $user, $pass, $email), don't escape them.

```
$fd=fopen("database.php","w");

fwrite($fd,"\$dbhost='localhost';
\$dbuser='$user';
\$dbpass='$pass';
\$dbname='$email';

\$dbh=newPDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$email',\$dbuser,\$dbpass);");

fclose($fd);
```

Quote version:

```
fwrite($fd, '$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="' . $user . '";
$dbpass="' . $pass . '";
$dbname="' .$email . '";

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $email . '", $dbuser, $dbpass);');
```

Comment: Please, provide how the op can fix it ;)

Comment: Going to edit my answer again so $user, $pass and $email can be strings.

Comment: Yeah could be, I putted both versions into the answer, one of them has to be for him. :D

Answer (score 0):

What error(s) do you get? Did you declare all the vars?

If you do $dbuser='$user' between "", then php thinks the vars already exist, so if they don't you get errors.

The thing you are trying is not really possible.

Comment: It says you cannot declare inside string, the above one works fine!!